# How to write a lexer rule that references a character?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to create a lexer rule that can read a string literal that defines its own delimiter (specifically, the Oracle quote-delimited string):

```
q'!My string which can contain 'single quotes'!'
```

where the `!` serves as the delimiter, but can in theory be any character.

Is it possible to do this via a lexer rule, without introducing a dependency on a given language target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this via a lexer rule, without introducing a dependency on a given language target?

No, target dependent code is needed for such a thing.

Just in case you, or someone else reading this Q&A is wondering how this can be done using target code, here's a quick demo:

```
lexer grammar TLexer;

@members {
  boolean ahead(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
      if (_input.LA(i + 1) != text.charAt(i)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

TEXT
 : [nN]? ( ['] ( [']['] | ~['] )* [']
         | [qQ] ['] QUOTED_TEXT [']
         )
 ;

// Skip everything other than TEXT tokens
OTHER
 : . -> skip
 ;

fragment QUOTED_TEXT
 : '[' ( {!ahead("]'")}?                      . )* ']'
 | '{' ( {!ahead("}'")}?                      . )* '}'
 | '<' ( {!ahead(">'")}?                      . )* '>'
 | '(' ( {!ahead(")'")}?                      . )* ')'
 |  .  ( {!ahead(getText().charAt(0) + "'")}? . )*  .
 ;
```

which can be tested with the class:

```java
public class Main {

    static void test(String input) {
        TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(input));
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        tokenStream.fill();

        System.out.printf("input: `%s`\n", input);

        for (Token token : tokenStream.getTokens()) {
            if (token.getType() != TLexer.EOF) {
                System.out.printf("  token: -> %s\n", token.getText());
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test("foo q'!My string which can contain 'single quotes'!' bar");
        test("foo q'(My string which can contain 'single quotes')' bar");
        test("foo 'My string which can contain ''single quotes' bar");
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
input: `foo q'!My string which can contain 'single quotes'!' bar`
  token: -> q'!My string which can contain 'single quotes'!'

input: `foo q'(My string which can contain 'single quotes')' bar`
  token: -> q'(My string which can contain 'single quotes')'

input: `foo 'My string which can contain ''single quotes' bar`
  token: -> 'My string which can contain ''single quotes'
```

The `.` in the alternative

```
|  .  ( {!ahead(getText().charAt(0) + "'")}? . )*  .
```

might be a bit too permissive, but that can be tweaked by replacing it with a negated, or regular character set.